# C# How to replace document by id

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is there a way to replace on the mongodb a document by ID? Instead of finding the document by some property, I'd like to replace it on the ID. With a document specified with the same  ID. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ReplaceOne`](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollection_1_ReplaceOne.htm) or `ReplaceOneAsync` to do this:

```
var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter
    .Eq("_id", new ObjectId("561674ef936e327431cbd349"));
var newdoc = new BsonDocument
{
    // _id is optional here, but if it's present, it must match the replaced doc's _id
    {"_id", new ObjectId("561674ef936e327431cbd349")},
    {"label", "new value"}
};
var result = collection.ReplaceOne(filter, newdoc);
```

See the docs on the topic [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/driver/crud/writing/#update-and-replace).